# How to read all files and read data from these files in specific folder in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to access all the files of any type(any extension) from a specific folder and I want to read all the data in from these files.

Comment: Hi Awais, welcome to stackoverflow. kindly update your question with what you have tried so far, what issue you faced, specific code sample input and expected output. Also read [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it will help you to frame your question in proper way

Answer (score 0):

You should start with learning about [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.8) (read directory structure and enumerate files) and [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8) classes. Then you might want to use [FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.8) class in order to read files' contents. Here's my simple example to help you get started:

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp"); // Obtaining DirectoryInfo object for specified path

foreach (var file in dirInfo.EnumerateFiles()) // Enumerating files, file is FileInfo object
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Reading {file.Name}...");
    var fileStream = file.OpenRead(); // obtainig FileStream to read from a file
    var bytesArray = new byte[fileStream.Length]; // allocating array to read into
    fileStream.Read(bytesArray);
    // Do some stuff with the data
    Console.WriteLine(@"Read " + bytesArray.Length + " bytes");
}
```

Please bear in mind that you need to add using in order to use System.IO namespace:

```
using System.IO;
```